# Asymptotic standard errors vs exact standard errors

Tags: regression, conditional-expectation, asymptotics

I am getting confused about the derivation of standard errors for the OLS estimator $\widehat{\beta}$. I have seen two different ways to derive standard errors: (i) from the exact covariance matrix of $\widehat{\beta}$ conditional on the regressors' matrix $X$ and (ii) the approximation from the asymptotic distribution of $\widehat{\beta}$. While the derivation from the asymptotic distribution makes perfectly sense to me, the derivation from the conditional covariance matrix is unclear. I understand that:
$$\text{Var}\left[\widehat{\beta} | X \right] = \left(X'X \right)^{-1} \text{E}\left[uu' | X \right] \left(X'X \right)^{-1},$$ where $\text{E}\left[uu' | X \right] = \text{Var}\left(u | X \right)$, i.e. the covariance matrix of the error terms that is generally a function of $X$ (heteroskedasticity). Then, my textbook claims that by replacing each element $i$ on the diagonal of $\text{E}\left[uu' | X \right]$ with the residuals squared $\widehat{u}^2_i$ we obtain a consistent estimate of the covariance matrix of $\widehat{\beta}$. However, from what I understand what we obtained is just an estimate of the variance of $\widehat{\beta}$ **conditional** on $X$, that still depends on $X$, hence this tells nothing about the **unconditional** covariance matrix of the estimator.

On the other hand, when we estimate asymptotic standard errors, we are able to approximate the **unconditional** covariance matrix of the OLS estimator. From what I understand it makes no sense to talk about "conditional standard errors", since in practical applications we are concerned about "unconditional standard errors".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variance of $\widehat{\beta} $ is always conditional on $X$ (regressors)
regardless of homo/heteroscedasticity and/or exact or asymptotically distributed errors. Sometimes the conditioning for $X$ is implicit but it is still used.

Moreover under homoscedasticity the form you have written simplifies to:

$$\text{Var}\left[\widehat{\beta} | X \right] = \left(X'X \right)^{-1} \text{E}\left[uu' | X \right] \left(X'X \right)^{-1}= \sigma^2 \left(X'X \right)^{-1}$$

But regardless of this simplification the conditioning on $X$ remains. Asymptotically, the formulas become a bit different but this does not matters to conclusions about conditioning.

Under homoscedasticity the unconditional variance looks like:

$$E[\text{Var}\left[\widehat{\beta} | X \right] ]= \sigma^2 E[\left(X'X \right)^{-1}] $$

but it is not known and is usually not considered.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Thus, when considering the asymptotic distribution of $\widehat{\beta}$ what we are really talking about is the conditional asymptotic distribution? Meaning that with "asymptotic variance" of $\widehat{\beta}$ we refer to its conditional asymptotic variance?

Comment: Yes, we refer on that.

Answer (score 3):

You say *since in practical applications we are concerned about "unconditional standard errors"*, but I don't think this is true.  Conditional standard errors tell us how uncertain we are about $\beta$, considering the $X$s we have. Unconditional standard errors tell us how uncertain we would expect to be about $\beta$ before we know what $X$s we have.  Since we typically do know what $X$s we have, the conditional standard errors are preferable.  They are also a lot easier to estimate; we try to avoid estimating the distribution of $X$ if we can, since it's multivariate and quite likely complicated.

You need unconditional (or expected conditional) standard errors for power/sample-size calculations in observational studies (in designed experiments you probably do know at least some components of $X$ in advance)